# Store colored output with a variable and print it with colors

Tags: git, bash, variables, colors

Consider the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# with colors
git status --short

# without colors
git_output=$(git status --short)
echo -n "$git_output"
```

This prints out "?? color_print.sh" twice, where ?? is first red then the default color. How can store and print the output to have the ?? colored also in the second line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to force git to spit out colors even when its output isn't going to a terminal (it disables colors when it detects that normally).

Unfortunately it doesn't look like `git status` understands the `--color` option you would need to do this most easily.

Which leaves you needing to tweak the correct config setting manually.

```
git_output=$(git -c color.status=always status --short)
echo -n "$git_output"
```